# Determining homomorphism using automorphism group of two graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, automorphism-groups

I wish to know the connection between the automorphism group of two graphs and homomorphism between them, if any.

Like all Kneser graphs $K(n,k)$ have the same automorphism group $S_n$. But, given another graph $G$ on $m$ vertices with an automorphism group of order $n$, how do we know to which value of $k$ there will be a homomorphism from $G$ to $K(n,k)$? For cycle graphs, it seems easy; for each cycle graph has its automorphism group as $D_{2m}$ from which we could say that two cycle graphs of order $m$ and $g$ are homomorphic iff $m|g$ or vice versa. Any hints?

Comment: I don’t think there is anything useful you can say in general. For example any bipartite graph is homomorphically equivalent to a single edge. Yet there are bipartite graphs with no non-trivial automorphisms and others with huge automorphism groups.